# MVC Partial view loading wrong data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am working on MVC3 application . At one page I am showing multiple partial views which takes model from different list of same class.

```
 @{Html.RenderPartial("UcPartialView1", Model.lst1);}
 @{Html.RenderPartial("UcPartialView2", Model.lst2);}
 @{Html.RenderPartial("UcPartialView3", Model.lst3);}
```

Everything was working fine until now.But suddenly I am experiencing strange behavior.
My all partial views load same data which is present in list1 even though each partial view  has different list and even partial views are different.
I tried debugging until each partial view where I can see actual data gets binded to partial view but while rendering it is only showing UcPartialView1 for all partial views.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You are passing the same data to all views.  Did you change something in the controller or the partial views? What did you change when the problem first appeared? Do the partial views bind to the ViewBag instead of a List<T>?

Comment: No I am passing different data and model to each partial view.No change in View only I added Authentication through Azman in controller

Comment: I havent tried through ViewBag .. Let me check and will keep you updated

Comment: No *don't* try the ViewBag! I was asking if you were bypassing the model. Anyway, If you passed different data, you'd get different views. MVC didn't just decide to pick a list at random. You may have a typo or a wrong assignment somewhere. Add a breakpoint at `RenderPartial` and check the values of the three lists. I suspect they are the same. You need to post the code for the partial views and the code that initializes the three lists

Comment: I tried with breakpoint at each Partial View and it takes the actual data which is different for each list but while showing it on page it is showing first partial view (data and columns) for all partial views

Comment: Got the issue.. I was replacing the table data in jquery.. I needed to apply to table id but mistakenly applied it to table class.. so all tables who are using that class got repaced

Comment: Please put the code of your view page

Comment: Thanks.. But I have already solved the issue as mentioned in my earlier comment

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used the different partialview for each list of same class.

Please try like Below, may be this will helps you to get solution.

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("UcPartialView1", Model.lst1);}
@{Html.RenderPartial("UcPartialView1", Model.lst2);}
@{Html.RenderPartial("UcPartialView1", Model.lst3);}
```

Note : **Here i used the same partial view for each class list.**